# (Discord.js) Detect arguments that are not a number

Tags: javascript, discord.js, arguments

I want to detect if the argument here is a number or something else. How can I do that? I haven't come up with a solution after ages...

```
if(msg.content.startsWith('>clear')) {

    var args = msg.content.slice(7);

    if(!args.length) {
        return msg.channel.send(`:no_entry:sign: | **Usage:** >clear <Amount>`);
    }

    // Here I need some sort of thing to detect if args = number
    if() {
        return msg.channel.send(`:no_entry_sign: | ${args} is not a number. **Usage:** >clear <Amount>`)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use JavaScript’s isNaN() to check if the variable is a number